# Continue out of FORALL loop in Chapel

Tags: chapel, forall

When you write it all caps like that, you really see the FORTRAN heritage.  Anyway, I can't get the `forall continue` syntax correct.

```
var ids = {1,2,3,5,7,11};

forall id in ids {
  if id == 5 then writeln("High Five!!");
  if id == 7 then continue;
  writeln(id);
}
```

How does one properly "skip out of this loop" when using `forall` in Chapel?

== EDIT ==

Error is

```
 error: break or continue is not in a loop
```

Comment: Well that's a terrible error message!  If you'd file a GitHub issue against it, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Done! https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/7626

Comment: A distributed infrastructure re-signalling of the local locale emitted break signal would be indeed a language challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the misleading error message, I think you've simply run into an unimplemented feature in the current version of Chapel (1.16.0).  I.e., I believe that this ought to work.  Let's co-opt the issue you filed in the comments section above to continue the discussion.